# setCurrentItem() on ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I create a custom view pager like this:

```
public class TaskPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public TaskPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new NotificationFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            break;

    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 5;
}


@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

}

and used on main fragment :

```
        mPagerAdapter = new TaskPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(-2);
```

in the **setCurrentItem** I have to which number to use until that i do not get an nullpoiner error?I want NotificationFragment() class is first start on view pager

***Edit***

whit  mViewPager.setCurrentItem(-1); i got blow error:

```
 Process: safarayaneh.com.anotify.debug, PID: 21484
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setMenuVisibility(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:120)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1034)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1248)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                               at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1028)...
```

Comment: why you set  `-2`

Comment: show error log please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read **[setCurrentItem](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int))**

> Set the currently selected page. If the ViewPager has already been
>   through its first layout with its current adapter there will be a
>   smooth animated transition between the current item and the specified
>   item.

**Problem**

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(-1);
```

Don't set **`-1 or -2`** . **index starts from 0** .

**EDIT**

```
switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new NotificationFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        break;
    case 3:
        break;
    case 4:
        break;

}
return fragment;
```

**WHY 1,2,3,4 BLANK** . You should try with

```
 switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new NotificationFragment();
        break;

}
return fragment;
```

**mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);**

Comment: with mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0) i got above error.1,2,and .. is blank because i fill that after fix this problem

Comment: obviously I have to fill 1 ,2, 3 ,4 .

Comment: my question is , before that i run this code I have to fill other switch statement ?

Comment: @sayreskabir yes

Answer (score 0):

Since NotificationFragment has the first position.
It's index is 0.

Therefore, it should be something like `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);`

Comment: with mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0) i got above error